# Why is the probability of one variable bigger than another differ for my Monte-Carlo simulations and theory?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, python, monte-carlo

Suppose:

$A \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$
$B \sim \mathcal{N}(1,\,1)$

In theory:
$P(A>B) = \Phi\left(\dfrac{\mu_A-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2+\sigma_B^2}}\right) = \Phi(-1)\approx 0.1586$

In my Monte-Carlo simulation I get:
$P(A>B)\approx 0.2398$

Why do I get the difference?

My code for Monte-Carlo simulation (Python):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

nn=100000000
a = np.random.normal(size=(nn,))
b = np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(nn,))
prob = (a>b).mean()
print(prob)
```

My code for theoretical calculation (Python):

```
norm.cdf(-1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot $\sigma^2_A + \sigma^2_B = 2$.

$$P(A>B) = \Phi\left(\dfrac{\mu_A-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2+\sigma_B^2}}\right)= \Phi\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 0.2397501$$

Here is R code to find norm.cdf

```
> pnorm(-1/sqrt(2))
[1] 0.2397501
```